# ~たいだとか why is there a だ here?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics

> 軽々しく死にたいだとか
>
> 愛を伝えたいだとか

I found these from some songs. If たい is considered an I-adj then I wonder why it's だとか instead of とか.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

だ between a verb/i-adjective and と/とか/なんて/etc adds an accusatory and/or shocked tone. In this case, this だ implies words like 死にたい and 愛を伝えたい are inappropriate because they are 軽々しい.

From 明鏡国語辞典:

> #### だ
>
> ❹ 《「…━と」「…━って」「…━なんて」の形で》**不適切と思われる相手の言葉**を直接引用して示す。多く、**非難・意外**などの気持ちがこもる。
>   「なに、行きたくない━と」「参加しない━なんて言わないで…」

It's even used like an accusatory sentence-end particle (masculine and rough, mainly in fiction):

> - はあ、怖いだぁ？ Huh? (Are you saying) are you afraid?
> - 何、知っていただ？ What? D'you say you knew this?

**Related:**

- [Is 「３人いるだと」 grammatical?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5693/5010)
- [what does としてもだ mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58949/5010)

**Bonus:**

It's also possible to say "verb + ですって?":

> - えっ、3人いるですって? Eh, (you said) there are three people!?
> - 宿題を忘れたですって?
> - 静かにしろですって? Do you (really) want me to shut up?

Comment: And sadly I can only find that definition on 明鏡, among major dictionaries including 日本国語大辞典 (sigh)

Answer (score 1):

〜だとか and 〜とか are really similar meaning. Actually you can use 軽々しく死にたいとか instead of 軽々しく死にたいだとか. If I were to say something like this:

> 彼は軽々しく「死にたい」とか言っていた
> （I don't feel anything about the word "死にたい" and him）

> 彼は軽々しく「死にたい」だとか言っていた
> (I don't like the word 死にたい or the fact he said 死にたい, I am thinking he shouldn't say such a things)

However...

> Yu-chan said "wanna quit the job".
> 優ちゃん「仕事やめたい」とか言ってた！

If someone said this sentence anxiously, I'd feel the person didn't want her to do so. In speech we usually use ~とか like this: someone said something and I wanna say the words.

If my friends told me 優ちゃん「仕事やめたい」だとか言ってた！ I'd feel something was wrong.

優ちゃん「仕事やめたい」とか言ってた！is more naturally.

And another situation: we use it for rumor.

> 噂によると、彼はお金持ちだとか・・・
> According to the rumor, he is rich...

I don't know if he is rich or not.

Someone said something but I don't know if it is true or not.

> 友達に聞いたんだけど、Aは死にたいって言っただとか.
> I heard from my friend that A said "wanna die".

I hear from my friend but I don't know if it is true or not. In this case, you can change ~だとか to ~らしい.

> 噂によると、彼はお金持ちらしい。

> 友達に聞いたんだけど、Aは死にたいっていったらしい.

and sometimes we say 行ったんだとか with the same meaning as 行っただとか.