# What is the difference between 何だと and 何ですと?

Tags: expressions

I noticed that in some anime (specifically, the Ace Attorney anime), the characters often switch between 何だと, 何ですと, and a few other slight variants. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

何だと is a plain form while 何ですと is a polite form.

Answer (score 2):

Who said 何ですと?

何だと is a more common form, and it's used mainly in fiction by many male speakers and "strong" female speakers. It usually sounds [more or less accusatory](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60016/5010).

何ですと is rarer, and it is virtually nonexistent in real-world conversations. 何ですと is used to show one's surprise (i.e., it's not accusatory), and it is mainly used by a sycophantic character who tends to feign politeness. In *Ace Attorney*, 亜内 (Winston Payne) is the typical character who may well use 何ですと. You may also see other speakers say 何ですと jokingly/comically. If 成歩堂 (Phoenix Wright) said 何ですと, it sounds comical.